# Problem with a pipe-highlighter in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a pipe, which highlight searched keyword

[image]

But when i clear input form, my pipe highlight every letter in a word.how to fix it? In this case when text is null

[image]

Code Typescript

```
@Pipe({
name: 'highlight'
 })

export class HighlightSearch implements PipeTransform {

public transform(value: string, predicate: string): string {

return value.replace(new RegExp(predicate, 'gi'), `<mark>${predicate}</mark>`);
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let Slide of SlidesFinded;">
      <td>{{ Slide.idSlide }}</td>
      <td>NULL</td>
      <td [innerHTML]="Slide.textSlide | highlight: text"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty regex matches every string, thus you got it highlighted. Add this as a condition to not apply highlight if "keyword" is empty and you will be fine.

```
public transform(value: string, predicate: string): string {
if(!predicate){
    return value;
}
return value.replace(new RegExp(predicate, 'gi'), `<mark>${predicate</mark>`);
   }
```

or something similar.